# How to use numba for speeding up integration using values from array to redefine the integral

Tags: python, arrays, scipy, numba, numerical-integration

I have tried to get a faster computation of integrals using python numba. Even though the timing using numba is almost 10 times faster for a single computation, when I loop the process for redefining the integral, it becomes awfully slow. I have tried using other decorators like `@vectorize` or `@jit` but with no success. Any tips on how to do it?

```
import numpy as np
import datetime as dd
from scipy.integrate import quad
from numba import cfunc, types, carray
tempText = 'Time Elapsed: {0:.6f} sec'
arr = np.arange(0.01,1.01,0.01)
out = np.zeros_like(arr)
def tryThis():           # beginner's solution
    for i in range(len(arr)):
        def integrand(t):
            return np.exp(-arr[i]*t)/t**2
        def do_integrate(func):
            return quad(func,1,np.inf)[0]
        out[i] = do_integrate(integrand)
    # print (out)
init = dd.datetime.now()
tryThis()
print (tempText.format((dd.datetime.now()-init).total_seconds()))
```

Time Elapsed: 0.047950 sec

```
def try2VectorizeThat(): # using numpy
    def do_integrate(arr):
        def integrand(t):
            return np.exp(-arr*t)/t**2
        return quad(integrand,1,np.inf)[0]
    do_integrate = np.vectorize(do_integrate)
    out = do_integrate(arr)
    # print (out)
init = dd.datetime.now()
try2VectorizeThat()
print (tempText.format((dd.datetime.now()-init).total_seconds()))
```

Time Elapsed: 0.026424 sec

```
def tryThisFaster():    # attempting to use numba
    for i in range(len(arr)):
        def get_integrand(*args):
            a = args[0]
            def integrand(t):
                return np.exp(-a*t)/t**2
            return integrand
        nb_integrand = cfunc("float64(float64)")(get_integrand(arr[i]))
        def do_integrate(func):
            return quad(func,1,np.inf)[0]
        out[i] = do_integrate(nb_integrand.ctypes)
    # print (out)
 init = dd.datetime.now()
tryThisFaster()
print (tempText.format((dd.datetime.now()-init).total_seconds()))
```

Time Elapsed: 1.905140 sec

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Note that you are measuring time for assigning variables and defining function included.

Also, `numba` can become (or seem) slower when the job is too small, as it needs time to compile itself and then applied.

Placing `integrand` outside the loop and decorating with `@njit` can give you some performance boost. Let's see some comparisons:

```
from numba import njit
@njit
def integrand(t, i):
    return np.exp(-arr[i]*t)/t**2

def tryFaster():     
    for i in range(len(arr)):
        out[i] = quad(integrand, 1, np.inf, args=(i))[0]
```

Time taken when `len(arr) = 100`:

```
arr = np.arange(0.01,1.01,0.01)

%timeit tryThis()
# 29.9 ms ± 4.59 ms per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 10 loops each)
%timeit tryFaster()
# 4.99 ms ± 11.5 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1 loop each)
```

Time taken when `len(arr) = 10,000`:

```
arr = np.arange(0.01,100.01,0.01)

%timeit tryThis()
# 1.43 s ± 208 ms per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1 loop each)
%timeit tryFaster()
# 142 ms ± 17.7 ms per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 10 loops each)
```

Comment: It would be also good to mention, that there are actually no global variables in Numba compiled functions. They are compile time constants and can't be changed without a recompilation.

Comment: The answer is correct, however, @max9111 's comment made me realize why what I was attempting to do did not work. Thank you to you both.